# Using calendar with AngularJs in a SpringMVC Project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, calendar

I would like to use a Calendar where i can add public holidays in my SpringMVC project. i'm working with JSP, AngularJs framework for javascript and bootstrap 2.x. i saw that there is UI-Calendar  http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ but i don't know how to integrate it in my Project.

i created the Controller and the views, just waiting to add my data and show them on a calendar instead of a Table.

thanks,